# How can I pass a mapping of properties to this method?

Tags: .net, properties, mapping

```
public static SelectOption ToSelectOption(this BaseDomainEntity entityModel) {
    return new SelectOption {
        Id = entityModel.DomainId,
        Name = entityModel.Name
    };
}
```

This method is used throughout our application to create select options. Most of the times, each model contains id and name as the fields we want to use. However, sometimes, we may have to use Id and ProductNumber or Id and Description, etc. Is there a way I can pass in a mapping for my function to follow?

I don't even know where to begin, but conceptually, it's like

```
Id => entity.ProductNumber

Name => entity.Description
```

That way I don't have to write a new function every time something needs a little something different from the common method. I would like to do this without passing a property name and using reflection, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will be too much code for you but see below.

```
 public static SelectOption ToSelectOption(this BaseDomainEntity entityModel, Func<BaseDomainEntity, SelectOption> selector)
    {

        return selector(entityModel);

    }
```

Usage is as below.

```
var option = instance.ToSelectOption(x => new SelectOption { Id = x.DomainId, Name = x.Name});
```

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines, but I just couldn't picture it in my head. This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll plug it in and see how we do. Looks good, though, thanks.

Comment: Could I take that a level lower and only use `x => new SelectOption { Id = x.DomainId, Name = x.Name}` somehow?

Comment: @Yatrix Not sure how that would work .. we are basically using a `Func<T,T2>` it expects a `BaseDomainEntity` and will return a `SelectOption`.

Comment: Nvm. I kinda messed with my head for a second there. Thanks again for your help. This is working great. Lambda's always throw me for a loop when I'm trying something new.